# How do you add flair to three20's Thumbnail View for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, view, thumbnails, three20

You know three20's Thumbnail View? We're building an iPhone app and want to use that view, except each thumbnail will be a user's profile picture. Then, based on certain flags downloaded as JSON from the server, we want to overlay a green dot on the bottom left of each thumbnail (or give each thumbnail a blue border) where the corresponding user is online (for example). do you know how to do that with three20? or any examples or tutorials online that do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't exactly the answer you were looking for, but you could consider modifying the image directly, or save two versions of the thumbnail (one with the overlay and one without), and switch the URL supplied to the TTPhotoSource when you need to change the display. Once you've updated your model, refresh the thumbnail view.